# Foundations and fundamental concepts of mathematics

Tags: reference-request

I've got a little question about the book "Foundations and fundamental concepts of mathematics (third editions)" from Howard Eves.

There are lots of exercises in the book, but the are only solution suggestions for selected problems in the book. I can not find a solution manual of ALL the exercises. Is there someone who knows where I can find it?

thnx!